# How do I mock a method of 'Socket' using MiniTest?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I have a short method which takes no arguments and returns a hash of local IP addresses in string form as keys with true as the value:

```
def self.local_ips
  # puts 'Getting ip addresses for this computer...'
  local_ips = {}
  Socket.ip_address_list.each do |address|
    ip_string = address.ip_address
    ip_string.sub!(/\%.*$/, '') # Removes interface from end of some IP's
    local_ips[IPAddr.new(ip_string).to_s] = true
  end
  return local_ips
end
```

This works correctly, correctly being defined by it is working as expected, but I would like to have a spec which tests this method. The problem is, `Socket.ip_address_list` will return differently on each machine it is on. I was wondering if there was a way while using MiniTest to mock the response of `Socket.ip_address_list` so that the method can be tested on any machine without fear of failure due to differences related to the local machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't mock which needed to be used but rather a stub:

```
fake_ip = Struct.new :ip_address
fake_ips = %w[ woot ]

Socket.stub :ip_address_list, lambda { fake_ips.map { |s| fake_ip.new s } } do
   Socket.ip_address_list.map { |ip| ip.ip_address }
end
# => ["woot"]
```